# Regex in .net - match first group in quotes, ignoring nested quote(s)

Tags: .net, regex

Trying to match the following using .net regex:

```
'match this                          value: (no match)
'match this'                         value: match this
'mat'ch this'                        value: mat'ch this
''match this'''                      value: 'match this''
'mat'ch this'' but '                 value: mat'ch this'
'mat'ch this' but 'not this match'   value: mat'ch this
```

Rule is continue matching until the quote is either followed by whitespace or end of string.

Closest I've come:

```
'(?!['])(.*)(?<!['])'
```

Which works in simple cases, but breaks as soon as more quotes are added.

Comment: Something like [`(?<=^').*?(?='\s|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/VYsMzi/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for all your test cases: `'(.*?)'(\s|$)`

The first part, `'(.*?)'`, matches everything enclosed in quotes.

The second part, `(\s|$)`, ensures that the quote is followed by either whitespace or end of string, as per the specification.